# Temporary / Intermittent "Access Denied" error on IISReset

Tags: iis, permissions

I have a system on which I intermittently use `iisreset`.

Mostly it JustWorks. But occasionally, it'll error reporting "AccessDenied" and leave the website somewhat broken. Immediately re-running `iisreset` then works just fine and leaves it back in the correct state.

What's going on and how do I fix it?

---

Specific error text:

> ```
> Attempting stop...
> Stop attempt failed.
> Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to
> use this command. Either have your account added to the administrator
> local group of the remote computer or to the domain administrator
> global group.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is explored and documented over here:

https://www.leansentry.com/guide/reset-restart-recycle-iis/dangers-of-iisreset#it-can-leave-your-server-in-a-stopped-state

The article offers that the best fix is not to be using `iisreset` in the first place (and offers various reasons and alternatives)

But if you need to keep using `iisreset` then on IIS 7.0+, you can call it in a slightly longer set of commands, that does the job "properly":

```
iisreset /stop /timeout:60
taskkill /F /FI "SERVICES eq was"
iisreset /start
```

*(Specifically [here](https://www.leansentry.com/guide/reset-restart-recycle-iis/dangers-of-iisreset#the-improved-iisreset-command-line-to-use) in that article)*

Roughly speaking, the default `iisreset` has a timeout for IIS to respond gracefully, and gives this (very misleading) error message if the timeout is missed ... which in certain cases it will do by default.